# How to export a PostgreSQL DB model to an org-mode file with tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, sql, postgresql

Having a PostgreSQL DB model defined in SQL, i would like to generate an org-mode file with a bunch of [org mode tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html) to document it.
So for each `CREATE TABLE`, it creates an org-mode table with its name and fields:

```
CREATE TABLE film_actor (
    actor_id integer NOT NULL,
    film_id integer NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE film_category (
    film_id integer NOT NULL,
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

...
```

Something like:

```
| film_actor | type | other |
| -------- | ---------| --- |
| actor_id | integer | NOT NULL |
| film_id  | integer | NOT NULL |
| last_update | timestamp | without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL |

| film_category | type | other |
| -------- | ---------| --- |
| film_id | integer | NOT NULL |
| category_id  | integer | NOT NULL |
| last_update | timestamp | without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL | 

...
```

Is there already some library that does something similar to this?
If not, any hints or strategy how to do the parsing?
My ELisp skills are kind of basic, so any hint will help.

Comment: If you only have these table definitions and have not created the tables, then this question is completely unrelated to Org, IMO.

Comment: There are more table definitions and tables have been created in postgresql. You can think of having a schema like this: https://github.com/jOOQ/sakila/blob/main/postgres-sakila-db/postgres-sakila-schema.sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it is more about PostgreSQL rather than Org Mode.
But anyway, to do this job you indeed need to know some about Org Babel to get things configured correctly.

I tested the following code on my machine (MS-Windows; if you're using GNU/Linux it should be easier):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
SELECT column_name,
       data_type,
       is_nullable,
       column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'lowercase_table_name';
#+END_SRC

Local Variables:
eval: (require 'ob-sql)
sql-postgres-program: "/Path/to/Your/psql"
org-babel-default-header-args:sql: ((:engine   . "postgresql")
                                    (:dbhost   . "localhost")
                                    (:dbport   . 5432)
                                    (:dbuser   . "postgres")
                                    (:database . "database_name"))
End:
```

[demo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x00OH.gif)

---

**If you want to use PostgreSQL in Org Babel on MS-Windows**, you MUST modify the definition of `org-babel-execute:sql` and then recompile the file `ob-sql.el`:

change

```lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:SQL ...
  ...
  ((postgresql postgres)
   (format "%s%s --set=\"ON_ERROR_STOP=1\" %s -A -P \
footer=off -F \"\t\"  %s -f %s -o %s %s"
           (if dbpassword
               (format "PGPASSWORD=%s " dbpassword)
             "")
  ...)
```

to

```lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:SQL ...
  ...
  ((postgresql postgres)
   (format "%s --set=\"ON_ERROR_STOP=1\" %s -A -P \
footer=off -F \"\t\"  %s -f %s -o %s %s"
  ...)
```

You also need to set your `PGPASSWORD` EXPLICITLY:

add

```lisp
eval: (setenv "PGPASSWORD" "Write your password here.")
```

to your Org file's local variables list.

Comment: Now I think this is just a PostgreSQL question because you can send the SQL statement to `psql` and copy the result and paste it into your Org file. Org will recognize the resulting table correctly.

Comment: Well, the point is to document the tables content as a way to show them to people that might not know about postgresql, org-mode or Emacs. My prefer way of documenting is org-mode because then i can choose to export it in many different ways.

Comment: This way relays on using psql, which i will test.
But it is only one of the solutions.
I was more interested in parsing the SQL model.
Because sometimes the same model is migrated to other DBs, like Oracle or MySQL.
Of course, taking the differences in order to make a proper parsing.

Comment: @shynur: can you please avoid animated GIFs or whatever is used in your image? I need to hide them because they make me dizzy and I have to scroll until they are hidden in order to read the rest of the answer. I don't know how widespread the phenomenon is, but I would be grateful if you could avoid them. A static image is OK (plus a link to some pastebin with the animation if you think it's necessary): that would go a long way towards alleviating my discomfort. Alternatively, is there a way that I can stop the animation?

Comment: @shynur's taking advantage of `psql` to parse the table format is ingenious and probably the best way to go about it. You can parametrize the query for different DBs and use the appropriate command-line program for each. But if you are intent on using your own program to do the parsing, you don't have to do it in elisp: you can e.g. write a python (or C, or C++, or Rust, or Ruby or ....) program to do the parsing: you can either put the program in a Babel src block or you can use a shell block to invoke it. So use whatever language you are comfortable with.

Comment: "Alternatively, is there a way that I can stop the animation?" - or maybe have a way to manually run it once. It's the looping that's driving me loopy :-(

Comment: @NickD Okay, I will avoid directly displaying GIFs and instead use links as substitutes.

Comment: I appreciate that - my eyes will thank you!

Comment: @NickD you can download the gif an use whatever video player has support for gifs to play/stop or move frame by frame. mpv does it and probably any coming from original mplayer or ffmpeg will.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that I don't want to see the animation at all, so I will certainly not download the GIF to play it. Doing the animation manually or going through just one cycle were suggestions that would accommodate the needs of the people who *want* to see the animation with the needs of the people (such as myself) who *don't ever* want to see the animation. The link solution that @Shynur adopted is ideal for me, but it puts the animation one click away which might inconvenience some people.

Comment: @shynur Well, my only concern is that this solution does not work for me... :-D
I get to execute it, and *Messages* buffer shows the temporary files created for the sql query and result. But result temporary file is empty, and the query must return data:

[] executing Sql code block...
Wrote c:/Users/tom/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-J36hzT/ob-input-lToIMt
[] Babel evaluation exited with code 1
Saving file c:/Users/tom/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-J36hzT/sql-out-RwQdYP...
Wrote c:/Users/tom/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-J36hzT/sql-out-RwQdYP
[] Code block evaluation complete.

Do not know why...

Comment: @nephewtom I updated my answer. It may help if you are using MS-Windows.

Comment: Ok, i finally made it work, though Windows path are a hassle... Needed to set this:
(setq sql-postgres-program "\"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\psql.exe\"")

Comment: @nephewtom I already mentioned it in my original answer: `sql-postgres-program: "/Path/to/Your/psql"`

Comment: yep, i knew that but when i tried before neither "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\psql.exe" nor "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/bin/psql.exe" worked, and then moved to other issue. Yesterday tried quoting the quotation marks, and that did it. Thanks updating the ob-sql.el thing!

Comment: @nephewtom: This is because there is a space in your psql path (`Program Files`).  ||| so ... please accept this answer for me? 

Comment: Accepted! By the way, do you know how to avoid being prompted each time with "Evaluate this sql code block on your system? (yes or no)" when running `org-babel-execute-subtree` in a bunch of source code blocks?

Comment: @nephewtom: see `org-confirm-babel-evaluate`